# How to navigate to new page after calling dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am having trouble getting my page navigation right using react and redux.  I have a component that has a link button.  When the button is clicked, I need to call a dispatch to update my state and then redirect to another page.  However, the redirect is not happening probably because the syntax in my action creator is not right.

As shown below in component A I had tried doing my navidation to the next page using history.push in Component A.  This worked, but it seems like it was loading the Dashboard page twice and more problematic, when I navigated back to Component A it did not rebind, so it seems it wasn't updating with the newest state.  Navigating back was done by actually clicking a link on the navbar of the page that has the components.

I tried using the ComponentWillMount and the ComponentWillReceiveNextProps in Component A, but that was causing an infinite loop.

History Helper

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export const history = createBrowserHistory();
```

Component A:

```
import { dataActions } from '../../_actions';

componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
}

handleLoadData(dataId) {
        this.props.dispatch(dataActions.loadData(dataID));
        //history.push('/dashboard')
    }

fetchData() {
    this.props.dispatch(dataActions.getAll());
}

render() {
    console.log("the value of props in render", this.props)
    const { dataList } = this.props; 

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Data List</h1>
            {(dataList.items) ? renderdataListTable(dataList.items, this): null}
        </div>
    );
}
```

renderdataListTable above just returns a simple table with button links:

`<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-link" onClick={(e) => self.handleLoadData(data.dataId)}>{data.dataName}</button></td>`

Action Creator:

```
import { history } from '../_helpers';

    function loadData(dataId) {
        return dispatch => {
            dispatch(request(dataId));

                dataService.loadById(dataId)


                .then(
                    dataItems=> {
                        dispatch(success(dataId));
                        history.push('/dashboard');
                    },
                    error => {
                        dispatch(failure(error));
                        dispatch(alertActions.error(error));
                    }
                );
        };

        function request() { return { type: dataConstants.LOADBYID_REQUEST } }
        function success(dataItems, dataId) {
            return { type: dataConstants.LOADBYID_SUCCESS, payload: { dataItems, dataId} }}
        function failure(error) { return { type: dataConstants.LOADBYID_FAILURE, error}}
}
```

Here is my App component which has the router setup:

```
import { history } from './_helpers';
import { alertActions } from './_actions';
import { PrivateRoute } from './_components';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        const { dispatch } = this.props;
        history.listen((location, action) => {
            // clear alert on location change
            dispatch(alertActions.clear());
        });
    }


 render() {
        const { alert } = this.props;
        return (
                <Router history={history}>
                <Layout>
                    <MuiThemeProvider>
                        {alert.message &&
                            <div className={`alert ${alert.type}`}>{alert.message}</div>
                        }
                        <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
                        <PrivateRoute exact path="/showdata" component={ShowDataList} />

                        <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
                        <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
                        <Route path="/register" component={RegisterPage} />
                    </MuiThemeProvider>
                </Layout>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { alert } = state;
    return {
        alert
    };
}
```

Comment: What I typically do is set a success flag in my redux state upon successful data fetch and do a check in `componentDidUpdate` of the mapped to props state success flag value. If it is changed and successful, dispatch action to clear flag and do a history push to new route.

Comment: What is the result of "console.log (this.props.dispatch (dataActions.loadData(dataID))"

Comment: If the promise

`this.props.dispatch(dataActions.loadData(dataID)).then(() => {
... your code
})`

Comment: Cna you add the code where you have configuration of your router ?

Comment: @Pranay I added the code for the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a callback function as a parameter to your action:

In Component:

```
callToFunctionWithCallback(dataId) {
  this.props.loadData(dataId, () => {
    //... here you do your redirect stuff     
  })
}
```

In Action creator:

```
export const loadData = (dataId, callbackFunction) => {
  // ... do your stuff here
    .then(
      dataItems=> {
         dispatch(success(dataId));
         callbackFunction()
         },
         error => {
           dispatch(failure(error));
           dispatch(alertActions.error(error));
        }
   );
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to work.  It causes component A to rerender after I fire handleLoadDate.  Theis then causes an error because now the state value for dataList is different.

Comment: I use the state to check what to render in the page, you can set the redirect there, or any other action, according to the new state.